# How do I get the context in Android widget in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

I need to access the context from the default constructor of an Android Widget in Kotlin.
How can I access the Context?
I know a few functions of the `AppWidgetProvider` have Context paramater but I do not use them.

Comment: "I know a few functions of the AppWidgetProvider have Context paramater but I do not use them" -- then your app widget will not work. "I need to access the context from the default constructor of an Android Widget in Kotlin" -- as with most subclasses of `BroadcastReceiver`, an `AppWidgetProvider` should not have a custom constructor. Your `AppWidgetProvider` instance lives for *one* call to one of the callback functions, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If my instance lives for one call only, how do I use class variables that keep their value between the calls?

Comment: "how do I use class variables that keep their value between the calls?" -- you do not do that, in general. Your process can (and probably will) be terminated between calls. If you want to use a `static` field as a cache, that is fine, but you will need to deal with the case when the cache is not populated.